# How do I disable syntastic for python files?

Tags: filetype-python, plugin-syntastic

I have the syntastic and python-mode plugins installed and they both include syntax checkers. I think the python-mode syntax checker is more versitle for python files so I would like to just use that one (instead of both).

How do I disable syntastic just for python files?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Syntastic documentation (`:help syntastic-pymode`) explains what to do:

> [...] To avoid both plugins opening error windows, you can either set
>   passive mode for python in syntastic (see syntastic_mode_map), or
>   disable lint checks in "python-mode", [...]

So you should be able to disable automatic syntax checking for Python files with something like the following in your `$MYVIMRC` file:

```
let g:syntastic_mode_map = { 'passive_filetypes': ['python'] }
```