# How to enable syntastic only for Python?

Tags: filetype, plugin-syntastic

There are various [questions](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2954/how-do-i-disable-syntastic-for-python-files) [and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030603/vim-syntastic-how-to-disable-the-checker) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818109/how-to-selectively-disable-checkers-for-certain-file-types-when-using-syntastic) about disabling/blacklisting certain file types.

How do I disable syntastic **for all but one** filetype? (Let's say Python.)

Comment: Have you considered investing a few minutes in reading the manual?

Comment: Do you think on the syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [syntastic docs](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/blob/1926693d1bcf786a526ff0980bc120ab4bad0dee/doc/syntastic.txt#L480-L513):

> ```
>                                                        'syntastic_mode_map'
> Default: { "mode": "active",
>            "active_filetypes": [],
>            "passive_filetypes": [] }
> ```
>
> Use this option to fine tune when automatic syntax checking is done (or not
>   done).
>
> The option should be set to something like:
>
> ```
> let g:syntastic_mode_map = {
>     \ "mode": "active",
>     \ "active_filetypes": ["ruby", "php"],
>     \ "passive_filetypes": ["puppet"] }
> ```
>
> "mode" can be mapped to one of two values - "active" or "passive". When set
>   to "active", syntastic does automatic checking whenever a buffer is saved or
>   initially opened.  When set to "passive" syntastic only checks when the user
>   calls :SyntasticCheck.
>
> The exceptions to these rules are defined with "active_filetypes" and
>   "passive_filetypes". In passive mode, automatic checks are still done for
>   filetypes in the "active_filetypes" array (and "passive_filetypes" is
>   ignored). In active mode, automatic checks are not done for any filetypes in
>   the "passive_filetypes" array ("active_filetypes" is ignored).
>
> If any of "mode", "active_filetypes", or "passive_filetypes" are left
>   unspecified, they default to values above.
>
> If local variable 'b:syntastic_mode' is defined its value takes precedence
>   over all calculations involving 'syntastic_mode_map' for the corresponding
>   buffer.
>
> At runtime, the :SyntasticToggleMode command can be used to switch between
>   active and passive modes.

You probably want something like:

```
let g:syntastic_mode_map = {
    \ "mode": "passive",
    \ "active_filetypes": ["python"],
    \ "passive_filetypes": [] }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could disable syntax checking for a specific filetype by overriding the default checker and tell him to use none.

```
let g:syntastic_filetype_checkers['python'] = ['python'] " will use python as checker
let g:syntastic_filetype_checkers['python'] = []         " won't use any checker
```

You could set this option to be empty for every filetype you don't want to be checked.